# Wordpress Plugin for View Events by yearly

Tags: wordpress, events, plugins

I am trying 2-3 Event Calendar plugin for showing our all events.
But by using these plugins we can list our event by Month, List or By Date only, for more event these plugins are perfect, but our event are very less(on an average 10-12 events per year only) so that we are not able to show all events to end users.
My query is there is any plugin available in wordpress for listing events by Yearly or any setting to displaying our all events(which is comes in one year) in one page. So that we can able to show all events in event page instead of monthly or datewise.
I hope you clear my point.
Please suggest me in proper direction.
Thanks in advance

Comment: i am waiting for your reply

Comment: How can i list the Events Yearly in "The Events Calendar" instead of Month, List & Date